# Openfiler - advantages of using LDAP authentication instead of local authentication

Tags: ldap

I am a bit newbie in Openfiler. What are advantages of using LDAP authentication or Active Directory authentication instead of local ?
Thanks.

Comment: If you already have directory services, you don't need to create all of those users in each individual application. This applies mainly to Enterprise deployments.

Comment: That's are all advantages?

Comment: If you don't understand why LDAP or Active Directory authentication is useful, then you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan on managing passwords on your own?  Expirations? Resets? Changes?

Let someone else do it. Use the existing user account in LDAP or AD and let whoever owns those systems take care of managing the pain of account and password management.  Why would you want to implement all that on your own.

Do you want to be responsible for secure storage of a password?  Let AD or LDAP handle that.

Why would the user want YAA? (Yet Another Account).

Use an existing account since it is much easier than dealing with all the work around account and password management.